# Default Gateway is a proxy server not router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip

Default gateway of my hostel in college is not the router. Infact, its the server of my college which is 10.x.x.x(I think its a proxy). So if someone wants to connect to the router to change its setting how would someone do that if he/she doesn't know the address of the router? Can anyone explain this as I am not able to grasp the concept of Default Gateway. If someone who wants to change the settings of the router how would he do that?

Comment: What did your research tell you about default gateway? Default gateway is where,  by default, packets are sent that are outside of your subnet. The router is most likely locked down by the IT dept, to make a change you would have to submit a request, and I doubt that would fly. This situation is most likely out of your hands.

Comment: In this case is the router configured to show hosts that the default gateway is 10.x.x.x?

Answer (score 0):

> if someone wants to connect to the router to change its setting how would someone do that if he/she doesn't know the address of the router?

The person that setup the router will/should know the IP address, since it's their job to administer it.

A router is not always a gateway, and a gateway is not always a router. They are two different things, that just happen to often be combined in to a single device (especially in single-subnet, SOHO networks)

> I am not able to grasp the concept of Default Gateway

Think of the Default Gateway as an actual gate in your back yard (your LAN).  Beyond the gate are other places you can visit (other networks).   If you want to visit those other places and yards, you first need to walk though the gate to exit your own yard.

By default this is your gate to get everywhere, and there is a default rule (called a Route) set that tells you that for any destination, exit out that gate to find it.

You can have multiple gates, with rules as to when you'd use them.  Example rule:  If you want to go to your neighbour's yard specifically, use Gate #2, because it's directly attached to both your yard and theirs (so it's the shortest/quickest path/route).

Now say you have many gates, with many rules.  Each time you want to go someplace you go over those rules and find the first one that tells you a specific gate to exit out of, to get to where you want to be.

If you go over your list of rules and can find nothing that specifically matches where you want to go, then you'd exit out the "Default" gate.

Comment: Is there a way I can get to know the ip of the router nearest to my pc?

Comment: Not specifically, `tracert` to an outside address and some guessing would probably be your best bet, but if they've got a proxy in the there it may not work (as the path may be masked by the proxy).  The best bet is probably to ask the IT staff that is in charge of it. :)

Comment: Tried traceroute :( its masked. Thank you again for helping me out!